# Convert times to designated time format and apply to y-axis of plotly graph

Tags: python, oop, plotly, timedelta

I am currently attempting to create a web dashboard for analytics in Formula1 using `plotly` and flask as per the article [An Interactive Web Dashboard with Plotly and Flask](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-interactive-web-dashboard-with-plotly-and-flask-c365cdec5e3f).

I have lap times in string format of MM:SS:sss (where MM is minute and sss is milliseconds) and I have attempted (python script below) to convert this to quantifiable values using `datetime.timedelta` so that I am able to graph them and manipulate them ( e.g find the average time of a driver over a number of laps). However when I try graphing the `timedelta` objects in `plotly`, they are displayed in microseconds.

Is it possible to create `timedelta` objects in the specified time-format and quantify them so that `plotly` will graph them correctly?

```
from datetime import timedelta

times = ["1:23.921", "1:24.690", "1:24.790"]

# convert to timedelta object
def string_con(string_time):
    new_time = timedelta(minutes=int(string_time.split(
        ":")[0]), seconds=int((string_time.split(":")[1]).split(".")[0]),
        milliseconds=int((string_time.split(":")[1]).split(".")[1]))
    return new_time


# compute average pace using timedelta objects
def average_pace(laps):
    laps = list(map(string_con, laps))
    return (sum(laps, timedelta(0))/len(laps))

print(average_pace(times))
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What exactly is the specified time-format you want the `timedelta` object to have and how does `plotly` need to have them quantified?

Comment: Thank you for replying @martineau, I want to convert the timedelta objects to MM:SS:sss format. When I try graphing them now, the objects are displayed in microseconds only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you are correct to convert from text to an analytical representation.  I have used **Timedelta** as well.   In some ways it would be simpler to use nanoseconds
- you also need to convert back in axis ticks and hover text.  I've used a utility function for this
- it all comes together such that you can create **plotly** plots of lap times that are correct and human readable ;-)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# get some lap timing data
df = pd.concat([
        pd.json_normalize(requests.get(f"https://ergast.com/api/f1/2021/7/laps/{l}.json").json()
                          ["MRData"]["RaceTable"]["Races"][0]["Laps"][0]["Timings"]
        ).assign(lap=l)
        for l in range(1, 25)
    ]).reset_index(drop=True)
# convert to timedelta...
df["time"] = (
    df["time"]
    .str.extract(r"(?P<minute>[0-9]+):(?P<sec>[0-9]+).(?P<milli>[0-9]+)")
    .apply(
        lambda r: pd.Timestamp(year=1970,month=1,day=1,
                               minute=int(r.minute),second=int(r.sec),microsecond=int(r.milli) * 10 ** 3,
        ),
        axis=1,
    )
    - pd.to_datetime("1-jan-1970").replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
)

# utility build display string from nanoseconds
def strfdelta(t, fmt="{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}.{milli:03d}"):
    d = {}
    d["minutes"], rem = divmod(t, 10 ** 9 * 60)
    d["seconds"], d["milli"] = divmod(rem, 10 ** 9)
    d["milli"] = d["milli"] // 10**6
    return fmt.format(**d)

# build a figure with lap times data...  NB use of hover_name for formatted time
fig = px.scatter(
    df,
    x="lap",
    y="time",
    color="driverId",
    hover_name=df["time"].astype(int).apply(strfdelta),
    hover_data={"time":False},
    size=df.groupby("lap")["time"].transform(
        lambda s: s.rank(ascending=True).eq(1).astype(int)
    ),
)
# make figure more interesting... add best/worst and mean lap times...
fig.add_traces(
    px.line(
        df.groupby("lap")
        .agg(
            avg=("time", lambda s: s.mean()),
            min=("time", lambda s: s.min()),
            max=("time", lambda s: s.max()),
        )
        .reset_index(),
        x="lap",
        y=["avg", "min", "max"],
    ).data
)

# fix up tick labels
ticks = pd.Series(range(df["time"].astype(int).min() - 10 ** 10,df["time"].astype(int).max(),10 ** 10,))
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis={
        "range": [
            df["time"].astype(int).min() - 10 ** 10,
            df["time"].astype(int).max(),
        ],
        "tickmode": "array",
        "tickvals": ticks,
        "ticktext": ticks.apply(strfdelta)
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. This looks amazing. More than I could've asked for. Off-topic, hope you enjoyed this weekend's race.

Comment: Just a note, I ran the code above and got an error:  "cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [int32]" for line `hover_name=df["time"].astype(int).apply(strfdelta)`.

Comment: are you using 32bit python?  timedelta will need int to be 64 bits `Python 3.9.4` pandas: `1.2.4`. plotly was `4.1.14` and after doing this I upgraded to `5.0.0`.  try using pandas data type instead `"int64"` NB use of quotes

Comment: I upgraded to Python3.9.4 from 3.9.1 while I was at it. And thank you, The key was to specify the integer sizes in ALL .astype() cases. `astype('int64')`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert a `timedelta`'s numeric internal values into different time units from what it stores them in, which are *`days`*, *`seconds`*, and *`microseconds`*.

Since you say you can't convert them to strings yourself, a potential workaround might be to convert them into a `timedelta` subclass which converts itself into a string the way you want.

One thing to keep in mind is that a `timedelta` can potentially hold huge values, which must be dealt with in some manner — so just saying you want "MM:SS.sss" format ignores the fact that theoretically there could also be days and hours involved. The function below calculates them, but only displays their values when they're non-zero.

The code below defines a new `MyTimeDelta` subclass and uses it. I've defined the subclass' `__str__()` method to return a string in the desired format. This former function is now used whenever instances of the new class are converted to strings, but the class as a whole remains "numerical" like it's base class. The subclass' `__str__()` method uses a private helper method I also added named `_convert_units()`.

```
from datetime import timedelta

class MyTimeDelta(timedelta):
    @classmethod
    def from_another(cls, other):
        if not isinstance(other, timedelta):
            raise TypeError('unsupported type')
        return cls(days=other.days, seconds=other.seconds, microseconds=other.microseconds)

    def __str__(self):
        """ Format a timedelta into this format D:H:MM:SS.sss """
        res = []
        days, hours, minutes, seconds = self._convert_units()
        if days:
            res.append(f'{days}:')
        if hours or days:
            res.append(f'{hours}:')
        if minutes or hours or days:
            res.append(f'{minutes:02d}:')
        res.append(f'{seconds}')
        return ''.join(res)

    def _convert_units(self):
        """ Convert a timedelta to days, hours, minutes, & seconds."""
        days = self.days
        hours, remainder = divmod(self.seconds, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
        seconds += self.microseconds / 1e6
        return days, hours, minutes, seconds

times = ["1:23.921", "1:24.690", "1:24.790"]

def string_con(string_time):
    """ Convert string_time to timedelta object. """
    split_time = string_time.split(":")
    split_secs = split_time[1].split(".")
    mins, secs, ms = map(int, (split_time[0], split_secs[0], split_secs[1]))
    return timedelta(minutes=mins, seconds=secs, milliseconds=ms)

def average_pace(laps):
    """ Compute average pace using timedelta objects. """
    laps = [string_con(lap) for lap in laps]
    return sum(laps, timedelta(0)) / len(laps)


avg = MyTimeDelta.from_another(average_pace(times))
print(f'{avg.days=}, {avg.seconds=}, {avg.microseconds=}')
print(avg)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. However, If I convert my timedelta objects to a string, I am not able to plot them as y-values on a graph because they wont be recognised as numerical values or time values. That is my reason, in attempting to manipulate the timedelta directly. [I have attached a image of what I am trying to do](https://www.f1technical.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12162)

Comment: I guess it's that "convert the `timedelta` objects to MM:SS:sss format" part I don't understand. Their format is fixed by their definition in the `datetime` module. That's why I asked what exactly it was you wanted to convert them into.

Comment: I modified my answer so now it creates a subclass of `timedelta` that converts itself into a string differently than instances of the base class do, which should allow them to be recognized the same way as it is, but display in the format you desire.

Comment: Thank you, I will certainly look into this. @RobRaymond provided a comprehensive solution to what I was looking to achieve. The trick was to convert the timedelta objects to nanoseconds(however I am going to choose to microseconds) and create an auxillary function to display the nanoseconds in string format on the plotly plot upon hover and on the y-axis ticks. My fault was not acknowledging that a function can change the way a value is displayed on a plot.