# Applying markers to certain plotly.express plots

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am working with pandas and plotly to map out f1 data. I currently have been able to retrieve the following data:

```
         driverId position                   time  lap
0          bottas        3 0 days 00:01:46.833000    1
0          bottas        3 0 days 00:01:40.188000    2
0        hamilton        1 0 days 00:01:44.859000    1
0        hamilton        1 0 days 00:01:39.625000    2
0  max_verstappen        2 0 days 00:01:46.339000    1
0  max_verstappen        2 0 days 00:01:39.613000    2
0           perez        4 0 days 00:01:48.257000    1
0           perez        4 0 days 00:01:40.612000    2
```

I have been able to plot the data successfully, and would like to apply markers to only selected driverId's e.g. just perez and bottas

To generate the lap vs time plot:

```
fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="lap",
    y="time",
    color="driverId",
    color_discrete_map=colour_drivers,
    hover_name=df["time"].astype("int64").apply(strfdelta),
    hover_data={"time": False, "position": True},
)
```

I have tried to use `fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines")` but that applies markers to all drivers. I have also tried creating a `fig.add_scatter` objects but, I do not want to abandon the line plot as it is more efficient for a larger number of drivers, and would introduce for-loops which I want to avoid. How would I go about applying it to a select group of drivers of my choosing, preferrably using `plotly.express.line`?

Answer (score 1):

- refer back to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146256/convert-times-to-designated-time-format-and-apply-to-y-axis-of-plotly-graph/68152217#68152217) for definition of data frame
- have defined `colour_drivers`
- for markers use `px.scatter` and `add_traces()` to line plot.  Drivers are filtered in dataframe

```
import plotly
colour_drivers = {d:c for c,d in zip(plotly.colors.qualitative.Alphabet, df["driverId"].unique())}

fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="lap",
    y="time",
    color="driverId",
    color_discrete_map=colour_drivers,
    hover_name=df["time"].astype("int64").apply(strfdelta),
    hover_data={"time": False, "position": True},
) 

fig.add_traces(px.scatter(df.loc[df["driverId"].isin(["bottas","perez"])], x="lap", y="time", 
           color="driverId", color_discrete_map=colour_drivers).update_traces(showlegend=False).data)
```

[image]